# C#: Cannot assign to foreach iteration variable

Tags: c#, loops, xna, foreach

I'm trying to condense this by wrapping it in a loop:

```
       if (pos.X + pixelRadius < 0) {
            pos.X = bounds.Width - pixelRadius;
        } else if (pos.X + pixelRadius > bounds.Width) {
            pos.X = pixelRadius;
        }

        if (pos.Y + pixelRadius < 0) {
            pos.Y = bounds.Heigh - pixelRadius;
        } else if (pos.Y + pixelRadius > bounds.Height) {
            pos.Y = pixelRadius;
        }
```

My first instinct was to do something like this:

```
        foreach (float coord in new float[] { pos.X, pos.Y }) {
            float upperBound = (coord == pos.X ? bounds.Width : bounds.Height);
            if (coord + pixelRadius < 0) {
                coord = upperBound - pixelRadius;
            } else if (coord + pixelRadius > upperBound) {
                coord = pixelRadius;
            }
        }
```

But of course then I get the error message:

```
Cannot assign to 'coord' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'
```

Is there any way I can wrap this code in a loop? Or maybe it's not worth the effort, and it's more readable to leave in the first form.

For those who are curious: yes, this is implementing wrap-around.

Comment: `pos.Y = bounds.Width - pixelRadius` Shouldn't that be bounds.Height?

Comment: Is this code even right? it seem to be forcing points to jump to the right boundary when the leave the left boundary and v.v.  If you want modulo math why not just use % rather than if?

Comment: @John: I think you're right. It looks like he is trying to implement wrap-around.

Comment: Ok, I added a modulo math answer.

Comment: honoring the question *title*, here's a related answered link from the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780584/foreach-and-modification-to-iteration-variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I think the first version is more readable. The second version batches stuff up in a loop and then ... tests to see which loop element it is??? Smells like `for...case` antipattern to me.

Comment: Anon is right.  Especially since you are just doing this twice.  If you had to do this hundreds of times it would make more sense to do the work to generalize.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is trying to do modulo math, so this is really what you want

```
pos.X %= bounds.Width;
pos.Y %= bounds.Height;
```

It doesn't give the exact same behavior as the above code, but it could if you just adjust the bounds and apply a bias to the point before doing the modulo.

or this if you need to have a bias

```
pos.X = ((pos.X - pixelRadius) % bounds.Width) + pixelRadius;
pos.Y = ((pos.Y - pixelRadius) % bounds.Height) + pixelRadius;
```

Modulo math is a better way to do wrap-around. It's clearer, and it has no branching.

Comment: mmm this is intriguing. Thanks.

Comment: What if pos.X or pos.Y are negative?

Comment: try it.  modulo math works on negative numbers (the result is always positive)

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could change coord, since it's a float you'd actually just be modifying a copy and not the value in pos.  Your best bet is to create a new method.

Answer (score 0):

I would leave it in it's original form.  When you're in the loop like above, `coord` is a **COPY** of the `pos.X` or `pos.Y` variable since they're [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).  This means even if you could update coord...you wouldn't be updating `pos.X` or `pos.Y`, but a copy of them local to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is a bad idea.

The code You have now, looks buggy, but it's structure is better, than some unnatural use of a loop.

If I understand what You are trying to do, I think You should have something like this

(I'm focusing on coordinate X. In case of coordinate Y it's analogous)

```
pos.X += pixelRadius;
if(pos.X < 0) {
    pos.X += bounds.Width;
} else if (pos.X > bounds.Width) {
    pos.X -= bounds.Width;           
}
```

This will work if |pixelRadius| < bounds.With and I'm assuming the numbers are floats, as the example with a loop suggests.

Modulus operator makes things a bit easier especially if |pixelRadius| > bounds.With, but be careful in case of negative numbers. You have to know exactly what Your language implementation is going to do with them

Using the modulus operator I would do it like this

```
pos.X = (pos.X + pixelRadius) % bounds.Width;
if(pos.X < 0) pos.X += bounds.Width;
```