# Foreach and modification to iteration variable

Tags: c#

What's the proper way to do this?

```
  foreach(Object obj in ObjectList<Object>)
   {
      Object changedObject= GetInfo(obj);
      obj=changedObject; //no good
      obj.prop1 = changedObject.prop1; //ok?
      obj.prop2 = changedObject.prop2; //ok?
      better way?
    }
```

Comment: A `for` loop. `foreach` is designed so you can't modify the state variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a for loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Object changedObject = GetInfo(list[i]);
    list[i] = changedObject;
}
```

You could also use LINQ, and append `.ToList()` if you need a list instead of an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var query = result.Select(o => GetInfo(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off creating a new list of objects, ie:

```
var newList = new List<Object>();
foreach(Object obj in ObjectList<Object>)
{
   newList.Add(GetInfo(obj));
}
```

Then either replace `ObjectList` with `newList` or just return it from whatever you're doing

Comment: Forget this Ahmad's answer is better